# How "BeingDebugged" field is triggered in process environment block

Tags: api, reverse-engineering

I want to understand how the API "IsDebuggerPresent" works exactly. 
From what I understand so far, the API checks the TEB structure, then goes to PEB offset, and then checks for the "BeingDebugged" flag within it.

What I couldn't find is what triggers this flag down in the core of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Since we know that IsDebuggerPresent can only detect usermode debugger, and not other kinds of debugger (such as a kernel debugger), then it most likely means that that flag is set somewhere within the [DebugActiveProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

To verify this, you can do a quick set up. Open up the following

1. Notepad (we will debug this application)
2. Ollydbg or other dbger(attach to notepad)
3. Memory viewing tool e.g [HeapMemView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/heap_memory_view.html) (attach this to notepad to watch the peb flag)
4. Another debugger instance to attach onto the first instance of
   ollydbg.

So if you breakpoint on `DebugActiveProcess` and trace it, you will see the it eventually reaches NtDebugActiveProcess. After it enters and come out from kernel space, the BeingDebugged flag is set.

If you wish to go deeper, you will need to be able to use a kernel debugger, and know how to set it up properly, otherwise you will just end up crashing your box.

I might write a more detailed response when i have the time in the future